Our program needs to use Outlook email to send emails
Our Node.js program used to use Outlook email to send emails without any issues, and provided user/password authentication using Basic.
However, the Basic authentication method has recently been abandoned by Outlook mailbox, so now email sending has failed.
I checked the information and it says that oauth2 authentication needs to be enabled,
May I ask how to fix this issue and what tasks do I need to do? Using Outlook can successfully send emails.

sender = "xxxx@outlook.com"
I use API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{sender}/sendMail to send Mail
get response :
{"error":{"code":"MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI","message":"The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise."}}
What's wrong?
